# monad unit property (in java)

Tags: java, monads, implementation

Supposing to define a DivideByN_Monad class in java. If I want a divider by 5 which type of method should I expect to have?  Is it the "unit" method?

Is monad-coherent to tell that the "unit" (or "return") method should be static and that when I invoke it passing "5" the unit method create/instance a sort of DivideBy5_Monad?

Is correct (in term of type-theory) to "think" to the unit method as the method-factory for context-specific instance of the DivedeByN_Monad?

TIA
Roberto C.

Comment: To get a monad, you need to have the `return` (or `unit`) and `bind` methods. Their implementations also have to adhere the monad laws. What is the DivideByN_Monad supposed to do?

Comment: DivideByN_Monad should have the ability to divide a given X value by the N value which is defined when the monad instance begin to exists.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, however I don't think such a construct is able to adhere the monad laws, because the division operation is not associative. But then again, I also don't have that much experience with monads. Maybe, you can add a meaningful code example of how you want to use the monad?